# Rolling Conditional Pandas DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

How would I be able to write a rolling condition apply to a column in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

lst = np.random.random_integers(low = -10, high = 10, size = 10)
lst2 = np.random.random_integers(low = -10, high = 10, size = 10)

#lst = [ -2  10 -10  -6   4   2  -5   4   9   3]
#lst2 = [-7  5  6 -4  7  1 -4 -6 -1 -4]
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a' : lst, 'b' : lst2})
```

Given a dataframe, namely 'df', I want to create a column 'C' such that it will display True if the element in a > 0 and b > 0 or False if a < 0 and b < 0.

**For the rows that do not meet this condition, I want to roll the entry in the previous row to the current one** (i.e. if the previous row has value 'True' but does not meet the specified conditions, it should have value 'True'.)

How can I do this?

**Follow-up Question : How would I do this for conditions a > 1 and b > 1 returns True or a < -1 and b < -1 returns False?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to do this with a little mathemagic on the signs.

```
i = np.sign(df.a)
j = np.sign(df.b)

i = i.mask(i != j).ffill()
i >= 0

# for your `lst` and `lst2` input 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

As long as you don't have to worry about integer overflows, this works just fine.

Comment: That worked for the first entry where a condition was not met, however, it didn't reapply the condition when I tried to use it for the entire dataframe.

Comment: @ZivLotzky Sorry about that... try it now?

Comment: Not exactly... I want to return True if a > 0 and b > 0 and False if a < 0 and b < 0. However, your code is returning True when either condition is met and False when neither is met.  Instead, if a condition is not met, I wish to return the previous result. For example, if row 1 returns False, but no condition is met for row 2, it should also return False.

Comment: As a follow-up question, how would I do this for conditions a > 1 and b > 1 returns True or a < -1 and b < -1 returns False? This might be a different answer since you do not have a uniform condition of greater than or equal to 0? @coldspeed

Comment: @ZivLotzky Yeah, I think the answer will be different... would you like to open another question?

Comment: just asked a follow up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251551/follow-up-to-rolling-condition-pandas

Answer (score 1):

```
i = np.sign(df.a)
j = np.sign(df.b)

i.mask(i != j).ffill().ge(0)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I came up with in the end... sorry for the retries, brain's a bit slow this monday... refresh your page.